# Trying to plot top 25 most frequently occurring words in a list and getting extra apostrophes and commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm testing some NLP code.  I hacked this together.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import re
import nltk 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
global str


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\path_to_data\\Datafiniti_Amazon_Consumer_Reviews_of_Amazon_Products.csv')


pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
print(df)


list(df)

df.info()
df.shape


# find percentage of missing data points
# if some arbitray number of data points are missing, let's say over 50%, we won't use this feature
df_missing = df.isna()
df_num_missing = df_missing.sum()
print(df_num_missing / len(df))
print(df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100)

# these fields have over 50% missing values:
# reviews.dateAdded
# reviews.id 


len(df)



# let's experiment with some sentiment analysis concepts
# first we need to clean up the stuff in the independent field of the DF we are workign with
df.replace('\'','', regex=True, inplace=True) 
df['review_title'] = df[['reviews.title']].astype(str)
df['review_text'] = df[['reviews.text']].astype(str)
df['review_title'] = df['reviews.title'].str.replace('\d+', '')
df['review_text'] = df['reviews.text'].str.replace('\d+', '')


# get rid of special characters
df['review_title'] = df['reviews.title'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
df['review_text'] = df['reviews.text'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')

# get rid of double spaces
df['review_title'] = df['reviews.title'].str.replace(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', '')
df['review_text'] = df['reviews.text'].str.replace(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', '')

# convert all case to lower
df['review_title'] = df['reviews.title'].str.lower()
df['review_text'] = df['reviews.text'].str.lower()


# let's do some exploratory data analysis
# we can plot counts of items in one column to get a visual clue about what's going on
categories = df.groupby("primaryCategories")
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
categories.size().sort_values(ascending=False).plot.bar()
plt.xticks(rotation=50)
plt.xlabel("Categories")
plt.ylabel("Number of Categories")
plt.show()


# let's check out results of a wordcloud to view frequencies of word occurrances
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(' '.join(df['primaryCategories']))
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.margins(x=0, y=0)
plt.show()


# perhaps a pie chart would look more appealing and be more useful too
# get top 10 categories; plotting all would give too many <1% of total and chart look wacky
s = df['primaryCategories'].value_counts().nlargest(10)
s.plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.0f%%')


# get top 10 reviews
s = df['reviews.title'].value_counts().nlargest(10)
s.plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.0f%%')


# 25 most common words in body
reviews_list = df['review_title'].tolist()
from collections import Counter 
Counter = Counter(reviews_list) 
most_occur = Counter.most_common(25) 
print(most_occur) 


# filter out stop words
# these are the most common words such as: “the“, “a“, and “is“.
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import FreqDist
nltk.download('stopwords') # run this one time
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
import re
import spacy
import gensim
from gensim import corpora

english_stopwords = stopwords.words('english')
print(len(english_stopwords))
text=str(reviews_list)

# split into words
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokens = word_tokenize(text)
# convert to lower case
tokens = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
# remove punctuation from each word
import string
table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
# remove remaining tokens that are not alphabetic
words = [word for word in stripped if word.isalpha()]
# filter out stop words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
words = [w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
print(words[:100])
   

# plot 25 most common words, with stop word stripped out
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
text=str(words)
tokenized_text = sent_tokenize(text)
#print(tokenized_text)
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokenized_word = word_tokenize(text)
#print(tokenized_word)
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
fdist = FreqDist(tokenized_word)
#print(fdist)
# Frequency Distribution Plot: most commonly occurring words
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#fdist.plot(25,cumulative=False)
fdist = FreqDist(word for word in tokenized_word if word.isalpha())
plt.show()
```

Here is a small sample of the tokenized text variable:

```
tokenized_text
Out[109]: ["['small', 'great', 'light', 'reader', 'easy', 'use', 'beach', 'great', 'price', 'great', 'buy', 'solid', 'entrylevel', 'kindle', 'great', 'kids', 'good', 'ebook', 'light', 'weight', 'makes', 'world', 'difference', 'taking', 'books', 'go', 'good', 'quality', 'best', 'ebook', 'great', 'product', 'good', 'price', 'excellent', 'reader', 'feels', 'like', 'real',
etc.
etc.
etc.
```

My chart looks like this.

[image]

It seems like I am getting an apostrophe and comma, as the first two characters in the chart, and all the strings are preceded by an apostrophe, for some reason.

The fdist variable looks like this.

```
FreqDist({"'": 12277, ',': 12264, "'great": 1747, "'tablet": 900, "'love": 427, "'good": 407, "'product": 351, "'kids": 336, "'kindle": 238, "'echo": 197, ...})
```

Something must be wrong with the code I posted above, because the raw data doesn't look like this, and I got rid of all special characters before I get to the step where I am trying to plot the results.  Maybe there is a simpler way to do this.  Any idea what I am doing wrong here?  Thanks.

Comment: Your raw data example?

Comment: The data file is named 'Datafiniti_Amazon_Consumer_Reviews_of_Amazon_Products.csv' and it comes from here: https://www.kaggle.com/datafiniti/consumer-reviews-of-amazon-products?select=Datafiniti_Amazon_Consumer_Reviews_of_Amazon_Products.csv

Comment: this may work `fdist = FreqDist(word for word in tokenized_word if word.isalpha())`

Comment: I mean `words` in your codes, not total raw data. Because I want to run your code. Without it I couldn't.

Comment: I just posted all the code that I'm working with.  I would have done it at the beginning, but I thought it was just overkill.

Comment: I think I find the problem and add my answer below. Please check if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `words` in code `text=str(words)` is a 'list'. `str(words)` will generate a 'list' str like `"['a', 'b', 'c', ',']"`. This cause your error.

Simple solution is replace your `str(words)` to `" ".join(words)`

Comment: That was it!!  The needle in the haystack was found and taken away!!  Thanks so much!!